# Self-hosted platform for selling pictures (photo stock agency)

Tags: open-source, images, cms, ecommerce, self-hosted

I am looking for a platform to sell pictures, like the platforms [Fotolia](http://fotolia.com/) or [Shutterstock](http://shutterstock.com/) or the commercial products [PhotoStore](http://www.ktools.net/photostore/features/) or [Photo Video Store](https://www.cmsaccount.com/photostore/online_demo/).

The platform needs to

1. be open source, since it is likely that I need to adapt things
2. run self-hosted, i.e. run on an open source server (Debian preferred)
3. provide user registration / login
4. support PayPal as payment provider
5. show image details (EXIF data etc.)
6. provide at least English as language
7. adds watermarks to images which are shown but not sold (preview images)
8. support image descriptions and tags
9. provide bulk upload capability and not web-based upload only
10. handle ~5000 visitors/month (ok, that's likely to depend on the hardware, but perhaps there is a statement about "performance per hardware")

It would be nice if

1. multiple languages are supported
2. the design could be changed easily (separation of content and style)
3. a voting system is integrated

Comment: Perhaps Zendesk? :P

Comment: @Nemo: if you could explain how Zendesk fulfills my needs, please add it as an answer. If it is what I found on the Internet, it's quite different.

Comment: Does anyone have experience with [Piwigo](http://piwigo.org/) + [Paypal shopping cart](http://piwigo.org/ext/extension_view.php?eid=499)