# Stock photo database

Tags: open-source, images, cms, self-hosted

I have a question quite similar to a [previous one of mine](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25159/self-hosted-platform-for-selling-pictures-photo-stock-agency), with the difference that

- I do not want to sell the photos but provide them for free (no payment needed)
- does not need user registration (all photos will be uploaded by the admin only)
- the amout of visitors is expected to much much lower
- no watermaks needed on images, since they are all released under a CC-something license

It needs to be a platform to provide pictures for download, like the platforms [Fotolia](http://fotolia.com/) or [Shutterstock](http://shutterstock.com/) or the commercial products [PhotoStore](http://www.ktools.net/photostore/features/) or [Photo Video Store](https://www.cmsaccount.com/photostore/online_demo/).

The platform needs to

1. be open source, since it is likely that I need to adapt things
2. run self-hosted, i.e. run on a Debian server
3. show image details (EXIF data etc.)
4. provide German as a language
5. support image descriptions and tags
6. provide bulk upload capability and not web-based upload only
7. handle ~100 visitors/month (likely to depend on the hardware, but perhaps there is a statement about "performance per hardware")
8. provide search capabilities

I have tried:

- [MediaGoblin](https://mediagoblin.org/) seems bad in uploading multiple images. It seems not to recognize the file's license from EXIF data. Also the layout did not convice me.
- [Lychee](https://lychee.electerious.com/) looks quite nice, but the usability is a bit unexpected. Navigating forward, back and up is not obvious.
- [Koken.me](http://koken.me/) has impressive screenshots but I was unable to find a live demo which I could use to figure out whether it really suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

I have never installed it, but you should be able to install MediaWiki with the correct extensions to make it behave like the photo database Wikimedia Commons.

The following extension will probably be useful:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryGallery
- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MultimediaViewer

Free and open source, tons of extensions available.

Checklist:

1. be open source: Yes
2. run self-hosted, i.e. run on a Debian server: Yes
3. show image details (EXIF data etc.): Yes
4. provide German as a language: Yes
5. support image descriptions and tags: Yes
6. provide bulk upload capability: Yes there are multiple tools like Vicuña that work with any Mediawiki-based server
7. handle ~100 visitors/month: Yes even on slow hardware
8. provide search capabilities: Yes

Comment: I have installed MediaWiki once and it was a nightmare :-) Maybe it's better nowadays. I can try once again